# JS simple boolean statement in if function - always getting TRUE value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, func

I am learning JS basics and I'm stuck on this super simple boolean inside if statement.

I just keep getting TRUE value from the if statement even when i change the value of the boolean to false:
[

```js
    var status = false;
    console.log(status);

    if (status) {
        console.log('true path taken');
    } else {
        console.log('false path taken');
    };
```

Please help:)

Comment: @Bergi: Ah, I was looking for a duplicate but apparently not well enough...

Comment: @FelixKling https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=window.status%20string had it (or at least another post pointing there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In global scope, `status` refers to the built-in global variable [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status). Every value assigned to it will be converted to a string:

```js
status = false;
console.log(status, typeof status);
```

Rename the variable or put your code inside a function:

```js
(function() {

    var status = false;
    console.log(status);

    if (status) {
        console.log('true path taken');
    } else {
        console.log('false path taken');
    };
}());
```